# Apache Redirect URL or Web Translation

Tags: apache, url, redirect, webserver, redhat

I am a total newb at Apache. So any help with this would be awesome.

So I have an application that's running on a Red Hat web server using Apache. Currently when you hit the base web server URL it gives the standard apache web page. I would like users who visit
    http://www.mysite/ and www.mysite/app1 
to be redirected to http://www.mysite:8080/app1. How would I go about doing this?

Also, is it possible to hide the redirect address (mostly the :8080) and just show the redirected URL?

Answer (score 0):

you should use mod_proxy from apache like this in your wirtual host

> ProxyPass / http://www.mysite.com:8080/
>
> ProxyPass /app1 http://www.mysite.com:8080/app1

to enable this in debian

> a2enmod proxy_http

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not using Debian :( This is Red Hat.